# Examples of Presenter First (or otherwise Test-Driven) Eclipse RCP applications

Tags: tdd, eclipse-rcp, gui-testing

Googling "Test-Driven Development Eclipse RCP" or variations brings up quite a few presentations, papers, etc. but no real example code or (even better) significant open-source applications developed in this way. Is there any?

Comment: same here! can you please share if you found any? thanks...

Comment: @Vikram No, I never did.